# native base need keyboard over the content

Tags: react-native, native-base

For example, there is a footer that I want the keyboard to hide it. Now I have something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdESi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3N5aL.png)

What do i need to do?

PS: I use native-base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `import { Keyboard } from "react-native";` and add listeners to it. Whenever the keyboard opens, hide the footer.

Something like:

```
  componentDidMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow () {
    // change the state of showFooter to false
  }

  _keyboardDidHide () {
    // change the state of showFooter to true
  }
```

Take a look at [Keyboard Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard.html)